# How can I add multiple domains in Gulp Browser Sync for proxy options?

Tags: gulp, browserify, browser-sync, livereload

This is my code

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'https://en-ae-upgrade.net-a-porter.com/',
    host: 'en-ae-upgrade.net-a-porter.com',
    open: 'external'
  });
});
```

The domain `en-ae-upgrade.net-a-porter.com.com` is on my local machine sitting on `443` SSL port. But I have all these domains in multisite:

```
en-ae-upgrade.net-a-porter.com
ar-ae-upgrade.net-a-porter.com
en-uk-upgrade.net-a-porter.com
ar-uk-upgrade.net-a-porter.com
```

And much more, about 11 in total. I tried a few arrays but nothing is working:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  var list = [
    'en-ae-upgrade.net-a-porter.com',
    'en-ar-upgrade.net-a-porter.com'
  ],
  var sss_list = [
    'https://en-ae-upgrade.net-a-porter.com',
    'https://en-ar-upgrade.net-a-porter.com'
  ],
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: ssl_list,
    host: list,
    open: 'external'
  });
});
```

Does the plugin allow this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way i can think of, is to start multiple instances of browserSync. They will need to be started synchronously.

```
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
browserSync2 = require('browser-sync').create(),

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'https://en-ae-upgrade.net-a-porter.com/',
    host: 'en-ae-upgrade.net-a-porter.com',
    open: 'external'
  }, function () {
      browserSync2.init({
        proxy: 'https://en-ar-upgrade.net-a-porter.com/',
        host: 'en-ar-upgrade.net-a-porter.com',
        open: 'external'
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can this work with multiple domains - 14 domains to be specific, and if so how, would this not cause bloating or slowing gulp down? Thanks for the reply so far.

Comment: I would think it works with multiple domains, just chain them in the same way as the seconds domain is chained in the example, as a dependancy of the previous `init` function. They will start one-by-one, so startup might take a little longer. I don't think multiple browserSyncs will be that slow to run, unless there are a lot of folders to watch.